# Rest initial conditions for ordinary differential equations and laplace transform method domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

My question is about the content in [these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iii-fourier-series-and-laplace-transform/laplace-transform-solving-initial-value-problems/MIT18_03SCF11_s29_3text.pdf) of the MIT OCW course on differential equations, 18.03. (anyways, I will try to keep it self contained) It is about the domain of the solution when applying the Laplace transform in ODEs with rest initial conditions.

First of all, let $\lim_{t\to 0^-} t = 0^-$.

It is stated that  the "rest initial conditions" of some differential equation $p(D)x=f(t)$ means that $x(0^-) = 0$,  $\dot{x}(0^-) = 0$, ... *and* $x(t)=0$ for any $t<0$.

So consider, for example, the DE 
$$\dot{x}+3x = e^{-t}$$
After solving the differential equation with the Laplace transform (I know there are easier methods, but these notes cover the application of the Laplace transform to solve DEs), we arrive to 
$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-3t}, t>0$$
The things I don't understand are:

$(1)$ How the initial conditions can be true, since for $t<0$, $x(t) = 0$ and so the left side of the equation is $0$ for all $t<0$, but the right side is never zero for $t<0$, so how can this be true?

$(2)$ Can this solution be extended to the rest of the real line or are solutions via Laplace transform only defined for $t>0$?

Comment: I think this doesn't completely answer my question. I still dont get (1) and I don't see the correlation between the input function being zero for t<0 and that happening to the output function, but thank you anyways.

Comment: There is a such thing as a "bilateral Laplace transform": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform

However, note that a solution of the form $x(t) = e^{-t}$ would not converge on $(-\infty,0)$ since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-t}=\infty$.

Comment: I guess you wrote your ODE wrong, it should be $e^{-t}u(t)$, $u(t)$ being unit step unction. Otherwise, how do you solve it with Laplace Transform.

Comment: Well, i guess it is wrong in the notes (Also, I have been taught that you can take Laplace transforms of functions without $u(t)$ in them, because the definition doesn’t require that; it is only concerned with the functions in (0, infinity) so the value for t<0 shouldn’t matter